# Why "to" is used and not "with" in the below context?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

**CONTEXT**:

*Nothing compares, nothing compares "to" you*.

The above context has been taken from a song lyrics. In this why "with" has not been used after compares. Which is correct "with" or "to" grammatically?
Many times, I have come across "with" after compare but this is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in most contexts, "**with**" and "**to**" are interchangeable prepositions with the word "**compare**"

[However, when you wish to say that one thing resembles another you use "**to**"](https://web.archive.org/web/20220824090532/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/compare-with-or-compare-to):

- I can't **compare** you **to** that girl. You are a lot more sexy.
- He **compared** that story **to** one written by J.K. Rowling.

Also, read [**“Compared with” vs “Compared to”—which is used when?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583/compared-with-vs-compared-to-which-is-used-when)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nothing+compares+with+it%2CNothing+compares+to+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNothing%20compares%20with%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNothing%20compares%20to%20it%3B%2Cc0